# Not able to start Postgres on windows

Tags: postgresql

While I am trying to start PostgreSQL using command "pg_ctl start" I get the following error:

> no database specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

Can anybody please help me with solution for this?

Comment: You typically start the Postgres service using `net start ...`. Why do you want to start the database server manually using `pg_ctl`?

Comment: You need to provide a **lot** more details: How did you install Postgres? Where is the location of the data directory? How did you initialize the data directory? Which Postgres version did you install?